# How can I share a single set of configuration values amongst all instances of my Sharepoint Webpart?

Tags: sharepoint, configuration, web-parts

I have a sharepoint webpart that will exist on many pages. The webpart has a custom editor control that I have developed to present the configuration options to the user in a more friendly manner.

Although there will be many instances of the webpart I require that each instance has the same consistent set of property values.

Is there a way using webparts to define a property as a site level configuration element rather than the current default / per page configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store your settings in the property bag of the site/farm. for instance SPFarm.Local.Properties.

Answer (score 0):

[SO - What is a proper way to store site-level global variables in a SharePoint site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008473/what-is-a-proper-way-to-store-site-level-global-variables-in-a-sharepoint-site/)

Includes references to MSDN articles explaining how to use the farm/site level property bags and the Hierarchical Configuration manager that's included in Microsoft reference "SharePoint Guidance Library"