# Deploy configuration file to the wss

Tags: sharepoint

I need to deploy a custom configuration file to the WSS 3.0. As I have read, there are 2 approaches:

1. Deploy the configuration file to the 12/CONFIG folder and then use stsadm -o copyappbincontent command.
   Adv: Suitable for large files.
   Disadv: All web applications deployed on the server will receive the merged web.config.
2. Use SPWebConfigModification class and using c# code add the required elements.
   Adv: We have the control over the web application where we want to deploy the  configuration data.
   Disadv: Cumbersome in case we have large configuration data.

In my case, I have a large block of data that has to be deployed. I want it to be deployed to a certain web application, NOT TO ALL of them. How can I do this using the first approach?

Comment: What type of configuration data is it?  Does it have to be stored in web.config?

Comment: I want to place there for instance log4net configuration data (I know that I can place it in a separate file). Another type of configuration are custom sections developed for different components.

Answer (score 0):

See [MSDN - Managing Custom Configuration Options for a SharePoint Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee855123%28office.12%29.aspx#odcwss3_ManageCustConfigOptions_SharePtOptions)

If your configuration may need to be different at different scope levels (Farm > Web App > Site Collection > Site and event list) then look into the Hierarchical Configuration Manager in the link below.

[SO - What is a proper way to store site-level global variables in a SharePoint site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008473/what-is-a-proper-way-to-store-site-level-global-variables-in-a-sharepoint-site)

So you could, for example, setup a configuration for all sites in a particular web app, or all site in a particular collection, or individual sites.

Not sure about your "Large Block of Data" - how large is large? I mean how large can configuration files be in KB?