# Custom web.config for asp.net web part in sharepoint 2010

Tags: wcf, sharepoint, web-config, web-parts, endpoint

**Base:**
I have created a ASP.NET web part to be deployed to a Sharepoint 2010 site. This web part is using a external web service, a WCF service that is hosted else where, not on the same machine as the Sharepoint site. The web parts are installed on the sharepoint server using a CAB-file that is created via a deploy project.

**Issue:**
My issue is that I have web service binding configurations in the web.config of my ASP.NET web part solution that I need to modify based on what customer is using it, so I need to be able to modify my binding address after installation (or during).

**Other:**
I have seen solutions using the SPWebConfigModification, but I have no local installation of Sharepoint so that is not an option. I have also seen pure C# solution where the endpoint address is hard coded in the assembly, but this will prevent me from modifying the address after compilation of the web part. The best way would be to have an external txt/xml-file that I can use from my web part to get the endpoint address from, or a smart way of updating the sharepoint web.config not using SPWebConfigModification.

so...

any one have a awesome solution to my issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use custom webpart properties that will contain the WCF endpoint information? This way you will be able to configure your webpart(s) after they are added to a page. The properties are reachable from the webpart code so you can generate the wcf proxy in the runtime with no custom config files in the solution.

this article might help you with the custom properties http://www.lamber.info/post/2010/05/21/How-do-I-create-custom-properties-in-Visual-Web-Parts.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the link, I think that is the way to go. Will try it and return with success or failure =)

Answer (score 0):

Editing web.config is almost always the wrong place to put something like this.

Maks answer is good and certainly the easiest option, if you want to store the address of the web service in one place to be used by multiple web part instances then this option may be better.

[SO - What is a proper way to store site-level global variables in a SharePoint site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008473/what-is-a-proper-way-to-store-site-level-global-variables-in-a-sharepoint-site/)

Comment: I don't have access to the Microsoft.SharePoint api on my developer machine and looking for a solution that is based on not using Microsoft.SharePoint namespace so that any developer in the team can write web parts to the product. So this solution is not working for me but thanks anyway.

Comment: If you're determined NOT to use the SharePoint API then this isn't a SharePoint question and shouldn't be titled and tagged as such!